# How to subscribe RxJava2 only if there are no subscriptions running

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using `Retrofit` with `RxJava2` and my code can trigger a network request at any time. I want to avoid retriggering the same network request if there is one already running. I know I could do this using some flags, but I think there's some special Rx way or operator of doing it.

What I want is:

- If some code asks for a network request AND there ISN'T a network request running, RUN it.
- If some code asks for a network request AND there IS a network request running, IGNORE it.

This way I can use `RxJava2` to get network requests, deal with network errors and avoid canceling and restarting the same network request multiple times, wasting resources.

Comment: Conceptionally it is the same as disabling a button until the background work terminates, which means usually setting a flag and checking it in the main thread before running the task again.

Comment: Well yes, but it's not good to use the UI as the control flow for some decoupled layer. What if my requests come from some other service? Or from multiple sources (like the UI and a "timed refresh" thread)?

Comment: How about some sort of single threaded executor -`Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` in combination with a `BackpressureStrategy.DROP` strategy where network requests are fed by a subject.toFlowable then flatmapped to the api request ... or something like this.

Comment: Seems complicated... I believed this was a common problem

Comment: "I believed this was a common problem" - you would think a google search would yield answers then? It's not really complicated (think of trying to do this without rx), rather than a thread pool out of your control (`Schedulers.io()`), you're dictating what thread network requests should be run on, dropping any requests that occur whilst the request is running - i.e. the thread is busy.

Comment: Yeah, I googled it, but knowing the right keywords for the issue is the key, or you get lots of other rx cases unrelated

Comment: The condition for "is a request running" could be the existence of a `Disposable`.